# Engagement split before decision split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I configured a Journey Builder where a engagement split is before a decision split. Because I just want to know if the contact open the email and if they  made a purchase, also.
is this possible?

Comment: If this is the best way (based on the data you have) of attributing the purchase to the email message (or at least counting it as an exposure that influenced a purchase) then this should be entirely possible.

You just need to make sure that the data to let you know that a purchase has taken place is available in your data model within Contact Builder, so you can then reference it in the decision split that follows your engagement split.

Comment: If this is really just about the possibility to put engagements splits after decision splits, the question is clear and answered. Otherwise you need to add information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data to support such action?

If it's a ongoing journey as it was already suggested to you, you have to bring ecommerce/purchase data to SFMC so that you can use it as part of decision split. If you are looking if purchase (no matter which one) happened, a simple boolean field would be enough to you.